# AJAX - replace javascript in page: ajax won't replace the javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, insert

I'm trying to replace a bit of javascript in my page via AJAX, but for some reason, AJAX wont replace it...
When I use:

```
    alert(document.getElementById('treintracking').innerHTML);
```

I can clearly see the javascript from the script piece: (this is the opening line of the javascript piece)

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="treintracking">
```

For replacing the script I use this:

```
document.getElementById('treintracking').innerHTML = responseText;
```

So, why does AJAX not want to replace the javascript?
I've tested, and the php file used to generate the replacement javascript, works fine.
I also took into account that the to-be-replaced javascript already has  tags around it, so I removed those in the php file.
But it still wont replace the content...

Also, if it put somefunction() in that javascript, will it then run, or do I have to do something special?

**Note: the javascript script is generated in a php file.**

***SOLUTION***:
I am now using this external solution, I don't have a clue how it works, but it works perfectly:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml
[I took the loading script from the page source, as it wasnt in the article itself...]

Comment: It may be replacing it but that code has already been executed.

Comment: How do you mean? It also doesnt show up in the sourcecode...

Comment: You can't "remove" JavaScript that way. Once the `<script>` tag has been executed, it has had its effect on the global context and removing or altering the `<script>` element won't change that.

Comment: Ok, that sounds fair. Do you perhaps have suggestions on how I **could** do it? Or should I make a new question for that?
**Idea?:** couldn't I make a function that is delayed by setTimeout, which calls to a function in the newly placed javascript?

Comment: @laarsk, it really depends what's in the script tag, and what you want to do to alter what's occurred. (e.g. if there are event listeners, if you want to revert content to what it was before the `treintracking` script ran, etc.)

Comment: Well, the new script should be placed inside the page, as it needs to run every minute, so it needs to be there. Existing javascript will only execute once, so I don't think that will cause any troubles...

Answer (score 1):

Adding JavaScript via innerHTML does not get evaluated.

If you want to add new code, just set the source to a new external JavaScript file.

So instead of using an Ajax call, you just set the src

```
document.getElementById('treintracking').src = "new/path.php?a=b";
```

Another solution [that I would avoid at all costs] is `eval()`.

Comment: Wow. That is stunningly simple! How actually is that different from an AJAX call? Because this seems tons easier!

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but also, that doesnt execute the new script nor replace the old javascript

Comment: @laarsk - You may want to ask a different question: I am trying to do ..., where the javascript would be returned by an ajax call. How can I get this to work.

Comment: Are there errors?  Did you try just a simple example with an alert?

Comment: I don't believe there were any errors, but, I already found a different solution: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to embed the new javascript inside a function, which may assign new contents to other functions, and then invoke the outer function.  Won't be terribly pretty.

Comment: How exactly do you mean "assign new contents to other functions"?